# How to loop through comma separated values in field to create new rows in other table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables I'm working within MySQL, one has some data, the other will be populated with this data, however - there is one field in the table that has comma separated values that I need to use to create separate (similar) records.

For example:
DATA TABLE: `"students"`
[Screenshot of table data is coming from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuTEl.png)

[image]

The data will go into a table called `"student_season_cross"` and will populate fields called `"student_id"` and `"league_id"`, but I want it to base the new records on "old_leagues" in the original table.

So, for example: data in the original table looking like this:

```
student_id  |  old_leagues
38          |  9, 33
39          |  8
40          |  3, 46
```

Would populate the new table like this:

```
ss_index | student_id | league_id
auto increment | 38 | 9 
auto increment | 38 | 33 
auto increment | 39 | 8 
auto increment | 40 | 3
auto increment | 40 | 46
```

I was thinking it would be some kind of loop, but I just can't wrap my head around it. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep search for mysql split string.

Comment: I think there's a better solution to be had with `FIND_IN_SET` and a join, working on that now for an answer

Comment: This will require number generator table to be used. At max how many comma separated `league_id` values are expected in a single field ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few times that `FIND_IN_SET` comes in handy. You can use this function to retrieve (specific) segments of a comma-separated list. Using this, we can join any student record to a record of the available leagues; thus going for a result like:

```
league | student
==============
1      | 38
1      | 39
1      | 40
2      | 39
3      | 22
3      | 23
```

Here's where you can use `FIND_IN_SET` to determine student participation in a league. I'm also assuming a table named `leagues` where you have all of the league ids under `leagues.id`:

```
INESRT INTO new_leagues (student_id, league_id)
SELECT origial_table.student_id
    leagues.id
FROM leagues
INNER JOIN original_table
    -- join a student record every time FIND_IN_SET matches
    ON FIND_IN_SET(leagues.id, original_table.old_leagues) >= 0
```

You'll have to forgive my inability to test this at the moment as I'm working on an upgrade to my development server, but hopefully you can glean a working answer from here.

Comment: This pre-supposes that old_leagues is a foreign key to an existing table (or one which can be easily created).

Comment: doesn't have to be a foreign key, but that would speed up the results. I would definitely recommend it for the new table, but I'm not actually certain there even is a `leagues` table. I made it for the simplicity of porting things over (sometimes a few dirty steps is easier than a single query for porting these things).

Comment: Where in the OPs question is the table "original_table" described? You seem to be confusing the concept of a foreign key with the DDL declaration of a foreign key.

Comment: I tried that (slight variation to accommodate table names)... but it created an entry for each student and league instead of adhering to the values in the 'old_leagues' field. 

I then tried this, but this didn't work either:
INSERT INTO student_season_cross 
        SET student_id = archive_students.student_id,
        league_id = leagues.league_id,
        season_id = leagues.season_id
        WHERE league_id IN(archive_students.old_leagues)

Comment: @symcbean the OP didn't offer any table names when I answered, they're just placeholders for the columns described. Drake: I'll do an sqlfiddle in about 6 hours to verify the statement is correct and functional for you (on a drive at the moment).